# is there any algorithm which can find arrays which do not have common key between them

Tags: php, arrays, math

```
$array1 = array (
    '1' => A,
    '2' => B,
    '3' => C
);

$array2 = array (
    '1' => A,
    '4' => B,
    '5' => D
);

$array3 = array (
    '5' => A,
    '6' => E,
    '7' => D
);

$array4 = array (
    '4' => A,
    '7' => B,
    '10' => C
);
```

I want to find out arrays which has all different keys, not a single key should be common between arrays.

`$array1 - $array3, $array1 - $array4` are two combinations which do not have common keys. Output of algorithm should be these combinations.

Comment: Do you want to get two arrays with no common keys, the _maximum_ possible amount of arrays with no common keys or the first array + all arrays with no common keys with that?

Comment: I want to get maximum possible arrays with no common keys

Comment: Do note that you've set only set `$array1` in this example and not multiple arrays.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I fixed that.

Comment: Whenn passing the four arrays in your code, what should be the output of the algorithm?

Comment: So in this example there would be no array without common keys?

Comment: $array1 - $array3, $array1 - $array4 are two combinations which do not have common keys. Output of algorithm should be these combinations.

Answer (score 5):

If two array don't have a common key, then

`count(array_intersect_key($a, $b))` should be `0`

Comment: using count(array_intersect_key($a, $b)), between first two arrays  key '1' is common, so on which basis we should choose the array to compare with 3rd array ? What should be algorithm to choose the array where we found common key. In this case if we choose 2rd array to compare with 3rd, they will have key '5' in common. so we will again have to choose only one between 2rd and 3rd. But ideally 1rst and 3rd should be selected as they do not have key in common.

Comment: @user1191081 Why not 1st and 4th?

Answer (score 1):

For finding unique key from two array you can use this

```
$newArray = array_diff_key($targetArray, $compArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function test() {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arrays); $i++) {
        if (($i + 1) == count($arrays))
        break;
        for($k = $i; $k < count($arrays); $k++) {
            if (count(array_intersect_key($arrays[$i], $arrays[$k])) == 0){
                var_dump($arrays[$i]);
                var_dump($arrays[$k]);
                printf('<hr />');
            }
        }   
    }
}
print_r(test($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));
```

Should solve your problem.